# When click on particular link show div at that position else hide others in jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

In this page i have done table listing and each tr have two link are :-
1) Adult and 2) Child 
When Click on particular link(for Adult or child) show the div at that position and all other position's div are hide. if next or any other link is click then hide previous link div.

I want to show the hidden div(as i given the hidden properties in div) at when click on particular link
------------Here are the **HTML** ::  ------------

```
<td>
    <div class="tab-inner">
        <p><span><strong>Space : <?php echo $row->space; ?></strong></span>
        </p>
        <p><a href="javascript:;" name="allocation" id="Adult_Allocation_<?php echo $j;?>" rel="#apop1_1" rev="Adult Allocation">Adult $<?php echo $row->adultPrice; ?></a>

            <!-- <div id="SpanAdultAllot"></div>-->
        </p>
        <div style="display:none;" class="adult-wrapper">
            <div class="adult-box">
                <div class="adultborder">
                    <div id="adultallot" class="adult-msg">Adult Allocation</div> <span class="adult-select-no"></span>
                </div><span class="adultarrow"></span>

                <label id="adult" class="adultselect">Adult :</label>
                <select class="selectorbox" id="adultselect" name="adult">
                    <option value="">--</option>
                    <?php for($i=1; $i<=$row->space; $i++) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php if($i==$row->space) echo " selected='selected' "; ?>">
                        <?php echo $i;?>
                    </option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>   <strong></strong> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php if($row->childPrice
        <>'0'){ ?>
            <p><a href="javascript:;" name="allocation" id="Adult_Allocation_<?php echo $j;?>" rel="#cpop1_1" rev="Child Allocation">Child $<?php echo $row->childPrice; ?></a>
            </p>
            <!--<div id="SpanChildAllot"></div>-->
            <?php } ?>
    </div>
</td>
```

----------Here **JS** code::-----------

```
$('a[name="allocation"]').live("click", function () {
    $(this).parent().next('.adult-wrapper').show();
    $('.adult-select-no').live("click", function () {
        $(this).closest('.tab-inner').find('.adult-wrapper').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: [live is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/), it's also better to use a recent version of jQuery, since they improve performance and weight

Comment: I still like `live` more than `on` :(

Comment: use `.css('visibility','show')` or `.css('visibility','hide')`

Comment: .css('visibility','show') or .css('visibility','hide') is not working....

Answer (score 1):

Add / include *jquery-1.9.0.min.js* file.

Create one `div` to show:

```
<div id="details_link" style="">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:$('#details_div').show();  $('#details_link').hide();">Show Link </a>
</div>
```

Create another div to hide:

```
<div id="details_div" style="display:none;">Test show and hide div
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:$('#details_div').hide();  $('#details_link').show();">Hide Link </a>
</div>
```

Some tips for avoiding errors when using different browsers:

- Don't write Javascript code in the `href` attribute, always put it in `onclick`.
- To hide `div`, write in its style `display:none` or `block`.
- Don't use `visibility=hidden`.

Comment: But problem is that only one td div is working all other are not work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @sayali! I've edited your comment to make it more readable and to format the code. You can do this using the buttons at the top of the text editor.

Comment: Code provided are useful but not for all div are separately show or hidden in my code requirement.... Because i have multiple link in different different div on each td.

Comment: Please try class instead of id for multiple div.